# Probability of event given two depandant events

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-networks

Is there anyway, to compute the probability of the event given two dependent events?
I know that Bayes can help if those events are independent, but what if condition events are dependent?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj0zNT_0NPdAhXLvo8KHR9nCnsQFjANegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F235087%2Fconditional-probability-of-dependent-events&usg=AOvVaw1ba5v2j66hrChEMgHj1KYr See if this answer is of help to you.

Comment: Bayes is also called Naive-bayes because treats dependent event as independent. Are you sure that they are so highly dependent?

Comment: Too old to migrate, but effectively duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235087/conditional-probability-of-dependent-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three (potentially dependent) events. By the [probability chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)):
$$ P(A,B,C)=P(A|B,C)P(B,C)=P(A|B,C)P(B|C)P(C) $$
So we can do
\begin{align}
P(A|B,C) 
&= \frac{ P(A,B,C)}{P(B|C)P(C)} \\
&= \frac{ P(B,C|A) P(A) }{ P(B|C)P(C) } \\
&= \frac{ P(B|A,C) P(A) P(C) }{ P(B|C)P(C) } \\
&= \frac{ P(B|A,C) P(A) }{ P(B|C) }
\end{align}

See [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281454/bayes-rule-with-3-variables/1281558) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176301/conditional-and-joint-probability-manipulations-when-there-are-3-variables) as well.